# How can I select a button with a type of submit using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have two buttons like this:

```
<button class="medium" id="register" type="button"
        onclick="location.href='/Account/Register'">Register</button>
<button class="medium default" id="login" type="submit">Login</button>
```

My Javascript selects the button by id:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        document.getElementsByClassName('form')[0]
            .addEventListener("submit", function (ev) {
                document.getElementById('login').innerHTML += '&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner" data-ng-show="fetching.length > 0"></i>';
            }, false);
    })();
</script>
```

How can I change this so the javascripts selects the button with a type of "submit" or a
button with a class of "submit" if that's not possible?

Note that I would like to do this because the javascript is used by many forms. I need a common way to find the "submit" button.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) to find the first element matching a CSS style format selector - it works as a method of `document` to search (obviously) the whole document, or as a method of an element to search within [only that element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.querySelector):

```
document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]').innerHTML += '&nbsp;...';
// OR
someElement.querySelector('button[type="submit"]').innerHTML += '&nbsp;...';
```

The latter is probably most useful to you since you want to find a submit button that presumably is in a form, and you already have a reference to the form: within a submit handler attached to the form with `addEventListener()` you can use `this.querySelector(...)`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/h6uuN/

The `.querySelector()` method is supported by pretty much all modern browsers, but (as always) a note about IE: supported from IE8 onwards. But since you're using `addEventListener()` presumably you don't care about old IE anyway.

If you did need to support old versions of IE you can use [`.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName) to find all button elements and then loop through them looking for the one that has `type="submit"`.

Comment: With my case I already have the form. Can I use that for someElement ?

Comment: Yes, `someElement` can be any element. I was just in the process of adding a demo that does exactly that for a form. See [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6uuN/).

Answer (score 7):

You can use querySelectorAll. It works back to IE8.

```
document.querySelectorAll('[type=submit]')
```

JS fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/X2RLg/

Comment: What are you supporting back to?

Answer (score 2):

Is important to remember that the button default type is **submit**, so the selector `button[type=submit]` wont match buttons like `<button>submit</button>`. This can be solved by adding `, button:not([type])` to the selector:

```js
document.querySelector('button[type="submit"], button:not([type])')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get all buttons on the page by doing this:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
```

Then you can iterate through the array and find all buttons with 'submit' as the value of their type property.

```
var submits = [];
var i;
for(i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
   if(buttons[i].type == "submit") { submits.push(buttons[i]); }
}
```