# trying to reach home page using click on login button with javascript code given below. Nothing is happening

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

**html code:-**

```
<button id="login" type="submit" onclick="lgn()">Log In</button>
```

**javascript code:-**

```
function lgn(){
    app.get("/",(_req,res)=>{
        res.render("index");
    });
}
```

but no action is done clicking on login button

Comment: `lgn` is in nodejs - why is the app.get in a function? that's not how express is used... what's in the browser javascript? you do know the difference between browser code and server code, right?

Comment: i have previously declared app.get() in my javascript file, but after calling lgn, again i want to call app.get() to move to home page. Suggest me if i am wrong..

Comment: You can easily access dom by using querySelector.

Comment: "my javascript file" ... browser or server

Answer (score 1):

I think what I read and understood is the content of this article, so I post it.

[How can I select a button with a type of submit using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840128/how-can-i-select-a-button-with-a-type-of-submit-using-javascript)

1. Set the id of the component.
2. Use querySelector to access.

Let me know if I understand anything different.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**I used this instead :-**

```
<button id="login" type="submit" onclick="location.href='/'">Log In</button>
```

javascript not needed

Comment: here is the reference:-https://www.plus2net.com/html_tutorial/button-linking.php

Comment: "javascript not needed" .. wrong `location.href='/'` is javascript